# How to create own angular service with XHR properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new about **AngularJS** things. Need to do file upload with other datas in form, I found some scripts and angular plugins but I am using my own **service** calls **$xhr**. I was able to send file but i got *error, bug*(*not real error-bug, i just named like that*) or i can not use AngularJS properly. Here it is:
.
**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('ngnNews', []);
app.factory('posts', [function () {...}]); // I reduced the codes

app.factory('$xhr', function () {
    var $xhr = { reqit: function (components) { ... //My Xml HTTP Request codes here }}
    return $xhr;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http','$scope','$xhr','posts',
    function ($http, $scope, $xhr, posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;

        $scope.files = [];
        var newPost = { title: 'post one', upvotes: 20, downvotes: 5 };
        $scope.posts.push(newPost);

        $scope.addPost = function () {
            $xhr.reqit({
                form: document.getElementById('postForm'),
                callbacks: {
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.success) {
                            console.log($scope.posts); //[FIRST OUT]
                            $scope.posts.push(result.post);
                            $scope.title = '';
                            console.log($scope.posts); //[SECOND OUT]
                        }
                    }
                },
                values: { upvotes: 0, downvotes: 0 },
                files: $scope.files
            });
            ...
    }
}]);
```

.
**HTML**

```
<form action="/Home/FileUp" id="postForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Post Title</span>
        <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="title" />
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="addPost()">Add New</button>
</form>
```

**SCREEN**

> [image]
>   Sample post displayed in list

.
**PROBLEMS**

> When I click first time **Add New** button everything works well until `$scope.posts.push(result.post);`. In console, **[SECOND OUT]** is here:
>
> [image: [SECOND OUT]]
>   First object has **$$hashKey** but second object which sent from server(added by `$scope.posts.push(result.post);` function) doesn't have. *I want to know why is this happening*? But it's not only weird thing, when I second time click **Add New** button, everything completed successfully (No new logs in console, adding new post to list shown **screen image** above).

**MAIN PROPLEM**
I pushed returned value from the server but **post list(in screen)** is not affected when first click.

**QUESTIONS**
 - What is happening? or
 - What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: I have added an answer but since you have not mentioned anything about the _error_ (`but i got error, bug`) i cant answer anything much on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong with respect to `$$hashkey` if that is your concern. When you use ng-repeat with array of objects angular by default attaches a unique key to the items which is with the property `$$hashkey`. This property is then used as a key to associated DOM elements with the corresponding item in the array by identity. Moving the same object in array would move the DOM element in the same way in the DOM. You can avoid this (addition of additional property on the object by angular) by using `track by` with ng-repeat by providing a unique key on the object or a mere `$index`. So with that instead of creating a unique key and attaching it to $$haskey property angular will use the unique identifier you have provided to associate the DOM element with the respective array item.

```
  ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index"
```

or (id you have a unique id for each of the object in the array, say `id` then)

```
 ng-repeat="post in posts track by post.id"
```

And since you say you are using `my xml http request code here`, i am assuming it is not within the angular context so you would need to manually perform the digest cycle by using `$scope.$apply()` is on of those ways.

```
       $scope.addPost = function () {
        $xhr.reqit({
            form: document.getElementById('postForm'),
            callbacks: {
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $scope.posts.push(result.post);
                        $scope.title = '';
                        $scope.$apply();//<-- here
                    }
                }
            },
```

But ideally you could wrap your xhr implementation with a `$q` and if you pass $q promise from your api, you wont need to perform a manual `$scope.$apply()` everywhere. Because $q promise chaining will take care of digest cycle invocation.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but i have same issue. Thanks for clear and useful explanation.

Comment: Please replicate it in a plnkr. track by _will_ remove the $$hashkey provided you are using it. Also your question does not even show where you are using posts. Sorry but I dont understand when you say i have same issue. What issue?

Comment: You need to perform a scope.$apply() since $xhr is something outside angular

Comment: Thanks for quick response, this is exactly what I want. I was read [**this**](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) post after your suggestion and understood.